# Script to create a shortcut to eclipse with workspace path in its target

Tags: eclipse, batch-file

I have a software package of about 500 eclipse projects, I want to create an eclipse shortcut that, once double clicked, opens the workspace directly.

Here is the steps that the script should perform:

Walk a given directory, if a subfolder is named `"Example"`:

1. Copy the full path (example: `C:/FW/project1/Application1/Example`)
2. Create a shortcut to eclipse (example: `C:/dev/ac/eclipse.exe`)
3. Make the Target field of the shortcut looks like this: `C:/dev/ac/eclipse.exe -data "C:/FW/project1/Application1/Example"`

Any hint about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [shortcutJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) - it is a `jscript/bat` hybrid and should be used with `.bat` extension:

```
call shortcutjs.bat -linkfile eclipse.lnk -target "C:\dev\ac\eclipse.exe " -workingdirectory "C:\dev\ac\" -linkarguments " -data C:/FW/project1/Application1/Example"
```

When I've created this didn't think about escaping quotes in arguments but I think as long there are no spaces in the `-data` path there should be no problems. If there are I suppose short path (8.3 notation) can be used.

With `-help` you can check the other options (you can set icon , admin permissions and etc.)